# How to get predictions on dataframe in fastai

Tags: deep-learning, fast-ai

I have defined databunch as

```
data = (TabularList.from_df(train_df, path='./', cont_names=cont_names, procs=procs)
                           .split_by_idx(list(range(500,3000)))
                           .label_from_df(cols=dep_var)
                           .add_test(test, label=0)
                           .databunch())
```

After training i am

```
p = learn3.get_preds()
len(p[1])
```

o/p is 2500 which is correct as

```
                       .split_by_idx(list(range(500,3000)))
```

this is 2500 numbers

But now i have other data of around few thousand inputs and if i do

```
for index in range(len(test_df)):
    predictions = learn3.predict(test_df.iloc[index])
    predictions = predictions[1].tolist()
    print(index)
```

It will take really huge amount of time. I want to pass test_df and get the predictions as was as

```
p = learn3.get_preds()
```

How can i do that ?

```
                       .split_by_idx(list(range(500,3000)))
```

Do we have way to replace this and pass data from other file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use fastai learner's `add_test()` method to replace the learner's original test set with your data. Alternatively you can also use `learn.data.test_dl = new_df` to achieve the same and then use `get_preds()` to get the predictions

Answer (score 4):

I have struggled with this for a while. The best method I have found is to do the following:

```
test_dl = learn.dls.test_dl(test_data) # Create a test dataloader
learn.get_preds(dl = test_dl) # Make predictions on it
```

Comment: This was really helpful for me when using fastAI2. Thanks!